# AttributeError on spacy token.pos_

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am working on tokenizing, lemmatizing and removing stopwords from a document. However, Spacy is throwing an error saying that the token.pos_ module does not accept 'str'.  I believe strings are the proper format, correct me if I am wrong. How do I fix this error?

```
words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_words = ['?']
# loop through each sentence in our training data
for pattern in training_data:
    # tokenize each word in the sentence
    w = gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(str(pattern['sentence']), deacc=True)
    # add to our words list
    words.extend(w)
    # add to documents in our corpus
    documents.append((w, pattern['class']))
    # add to our classes list
    if pattern['class'] not in classes:
        classes.append(pattern['class'])

nltk.download('stopwords')
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
stop_words.extend(["be", "use", "fig"])
words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words] 

# stem and lower each word and remove duplicates
import en_core_web_lg
nlp = en_core_web_lg.load()
print(words[0:10])

words = [token.lemma_ for token in words if token.pos_ in postags]
words = list(set(words))

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-5c31e2b5a13c> in <module>()
     26 
     27 from spacy import tokens
---> 28 words = [token.lemma_ for token in words if token.pos in postags]
     29 words = list(set(words))
     30 

<ipython-input-72-5c31e2b5a13c> in <listcomp>(.0)
     26 
     27 from spacy import tokens
---> 28 words = [token.lemma_ for token in words if token.pos in postags]
     29 words = list(set(words))
     30 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pos'
```

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The error is saying that `pos` as a method does not exist for a `str`.

Comment: You are redefining the `words` var a lot. It looks like `words` is first defined as a list of strings, not spacy `token` objects. With that in mind, they will not have the appropriate `.pos` and `.lemma_` attrs

Answer (score 2):

Your code shows `words` as follows:

```
words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]
```

Each `word` is a `stringType` and is not a `token` object from spaCy. Thus, you are seeing that error.

To fix this:

```
# Make the spaCy doc obj for the sentence
doc = nlp(pattern['sentence'])

# get words (tokens) for the sentence
words = [w for w in doc.sents[0]]

# Now words will have the .pos_ tag and .lemma_
toks = [token.lemma_ for token in words if token.pos_ not in postags]
```